# PyQt:How to get contents of selected cell in table widget?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a table widget with cells containing strings.I want to select a cell and then pushing a button to get the contents of the cell.

I thought to use `tableWidget.currentItem()`, but I get a QTableWidgetItem object.

For the button and the table I use QtDesigner.Any tips?Thanks.

Comment: What was your process in trying to figure out an answer once you saw that currentItem() was returning a QTableWidgetItem?

Answer (score 3):

Look at [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidgetitem.html#text). It's *really* useful:

```
tableWidget.currentItem().text()
```